# TypeError: Cannot read property 'propName' of null

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, ionic2

I always get this error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'propName' of null

Here is my Typescript.

**handlu-prop.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, ModalController, NavController, NavParams, ActionSheetController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { AlertController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { AngularFireDatabase,FirebaseObjectObservable } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';
import { ConAgentsPage } from '../conagents/conagents';
import { HandluPage } from '../handlu/handlu';

import { PropertyItem } from '../../models/property-item/PropItem.interface';


@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-handlu-prop',
  templateUrl: 'handlu-prop.html',
})
export class HandluPropPage {

propertyItemSubscription: Subscription;
propertyItem = {} as PropertyItem;
propertyItemRef$: FirebaseObjectObservable<PropertyItem>;

  constructor(private database: AngularFireDatabase, 
  private modCtrl: ModalController, 
  public navCtrl: NavController, 
  public navParams: NavParams, 
  public alertCtrl: AlertController) {


  const propertyItemId = this.navParams.get('$key');
    console.log(propertyItemId);

  this.propertyItemRef$ = this.database.object(`Property/${propertyItemId}`).valueChanges();
  this.propertyItemSubscription = 
    this.propertyItemRef$.subscribe( propertyItem => this.propertyItem = propertyItem );
  }

 ionViewWillLeave() {
   this.propertyItemSubscription.unsubscribe();
  }
```

**handlu-prop.html (here is a part of my template)**

```
<h2>{{propertyItem.propName}}</h2>
```

Comment: did you declared a propName variable in handlu-prop.js file ?

Comment: i'm sorry i'm really new to this. where could i possibly find that?

Comment: or does it have something to do with the propertyItemId..?

Comment: You have to learn java script basics , if you are new to this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot read property of 'xxx' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43840008/cannot-read-property-of-xxx-of-undefined)

Answer (score 1):

Try modifying your HTML file to this
`<h2>{{ propertyItem?.propName }}</h2>`
the `?` serves the purpose of checking if this element is defined or not, it avoids crashing the app into that error.